# ¿Cómo automatizar la detección del tipo de columna de un archivo csv para un script de creación de tablas?

Tags: python, sql, csv, pgadmin

Tengo un largo archivo csv y quiero crear una tabla en pgAdmin4 para enviarla sobre Microsoft Azure.

```
IDI GKID    S01Q01  S02Q01_Gender ...
100093  enq030059569748fc89091fdd91cc337cac44eca90  Yes, I agree    Female ...
```

Estoy haciendo el script para crear la tabla. Sin embargo, dado el número de columnas me gustaría automatizarlo para obtener el script que me permitiria anadir el csv a la database en pgAdmin4 para Microsoft Azure.

Entonces, tras transposar el header del csv, obtengo:

```
    IDI
    GKID
    S01Q01
    S02Q01_Gender
    ...
```

Estoy haciendo el script para crear la tabla. Sin embargo, dado el número de columnas me gustaría, en el mejor de los casos, automatizar la detección del tipo de columna para poder escribirla en la parte correcta, en el peor de los casos poner un tipo genérico del tipo TEXTO.

Hasta ahora intente

```
output = ""
file_name = "columns.txt"
string_to_add = " TINYTEXT,"

with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    file_lines = [''.join([x.strip(), string_to_add, '\n']) for x in f.readlines()]

with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(file_lines)
```

Me devuelve :

```
IDI TINYTEXT,
GKID TINYTEXT,
S01Q01 TINYTEXT,
S02Q01_Gender TINYTEXT,
...
```

Y, entonces, puedo hacer:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
IDI TINYTEXT,
GKID TINYTEXT,
S01Q01 TINYTEXT,
S02Q01_Gender TINYTEXT,
...
```

Pero no soy seguro que esta sufficiente

Comment: mmm para detectar el tipo de dato por columna y ponerlo asi en tu `CREATE TABLE` se me ocurre que verifiques los datos de cada columna talvez con expresiones regulares, algo como:
`if re.match('^\d+$', str(dato_columna)) != None` para saber si es un número, e ir comparando si algun registro de la columna no es un número tomar ese campo como `TEXT` y sino pues lo tomas con el tipo correspondiente al número. Bueno es una idea espero se comprenda el ejemplo

Comment: Usa `pandas` y deja que haga el trabajo sucio de detctar los tipos de cada columna. También puedes usar `pandas` para meter los datos en la BD con el método `to_sql` de un `DataFrame`.